# Display data from firebase in an UITableView CustomCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, custom-cell, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an iOS application using swift, with firebase. I have 4 labels in a Prototype Cell of my UITableView and I want to fill them with data from firebase. Thanks for helping me ;)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var date: NSDate!
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://HIDDEN.firebaseio.com")
let childRef = Firebase(url:"https://HIDDEN.firebaseio.com/User")
let childChildRef = Firebase(url:"https://HIDDEN.firebaseio.com/User/List")

 @IBOutlet var tableList: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    as! CustomCell


    childChildRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in

         cell.name.text = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Name"))![indexPath.row]
         cell.age.text = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Age"))![indexPath.row]
         cell.stat.text = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Stat"))![indexPath.row]
         cell.notes.text = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Notes"))![indexPath.row]

        self.tableList.reloadData()
    })
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: "cell.name.text = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Name"))"  without the "[indexPath.row]" => no error, but the value doesn't display so i tried to fix that with the indexPath, and I got the error "unavailable subsript" because i just don't know how to fix that correct.

Comment: Why are you reloading tableview inside CellForRow?